# Why do templates allow constexpr function members with non-constexpr constructors?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr

Using C++14. Why will this compile:

```
template<unsigned N>
constexpr bool foo()
{
    std::array<char, N> arr;
    return true;
}
```

but not this?

```
constexpr bool foo()
{
    std::array<char, 10> arr; // Non-constexpr constructor 'array' cannot be used in a constant expression
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try instantiating the first function template.

Comment: @0x499602D2: with the corrected question, the first example can be instantiated (e.g. `foo<10>();`) without error.

Comment: @Daniel: [No it can't.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8f449a34a2a19da)

Comment: It's compiling fine for me with Clang.

Comment: @Daniel the existence of a C++ compiler that will compile some bit of code is not strong evidence that the code is valid C++, **especially** with relatively new C++14 features.

Comment: I think clang is wrong to compile it because the [relaxed C++14 `constexpr` restrictions](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Relaxed_constexpr_restrictions) allow variable declarations iff those declarations contain initializers. I don't think gcc has this C++14 feature yet however as its error message corresponds to the C++11 standard.

Comment: Which version of clang are you using? It doesn't compile for me with 3.4.1. It compiles on 3.5 but not if you try to use it in a context that requires a constant expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

§7.1.5 [dcl.constexpr]/p6:

> If the instantiated template specialization of a `constexpr` function
>   template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy
>   the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr`
>   constructor, that specialization is still a `constexpr` function or
>   `constexpr` constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot
>   appear in a constant expression. If no specialization of the template
>   would satisfy the requirements for a `constexpr` function or
>   `constexpr` constructor when considered as a non-template function or
>   constructor, the template is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

It is valid for `constexpr` function templates to have some specializations that do not satisfy the `constexpr` requirements, and it is valid to use those specializations as long as they are not in a context that requires a constant expression.

It isn't valid, however, if no specialization of the template could satisfy `constexpr` requirements. Since in the general case it is impossible to determine whether all possible instantiations of a function template will fail to satisfy the `constexpr` requirements,the standard doesn't require a diagnostic. Hence, your code is ill-formed with no diagnostic required - the compiler can, but is not required to, report an error.

Comment: How does his code not satisfy `constexpr` requirements?

Comment: @0x499602D2 It defines a variable of type `std::array<char, N>`, for which no initialization is performed.

Answer (score 2):

They don't. Your test is flawed.

The problem is not detected until you actually attempt to instantiate the broken function template.

Comment: Apologies, I'd made an error in the original question. Your answer was originally of course correct, but I don't think the question would be very helpful as it was, so I've corrected it.

Comment: The first example is compiling fine for me with an instantiation under Clang.

Comment: @Daniel: Then your question should be "_is_ this valid" not assuming it's invalid and asking why your one particular compiler allows it.