# Why is a constexpr member function only valid when returning a custom type in a generic class?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, constexpr

So is this a bug or intentional (using VS2017 update 15.3.4)?

The following does not compile because `CustomType` is a nonliteral.

```
class A
{
public:
    // ... some constructors
    inline constexpr auto Value() const { return _value; }
private:
    const CustomType _value;
}
```

But this is totally fine:

```
template< //... some templates
    >
class A
{
public:
    // ... some constructors
    inline constexpr auto Value() const { return _value; }
private:
    const CustomType _value;
}
```

Why!? Is there any benefit I am missing out on in the first instance by not using a constexpr? Is there any benefit I am receiving in the second instance by using constexpr or is the compiler simply being lazy and completely ignores the mistake? Or is all this intentionally done because there is some difference between a generic class and a non-generic class that I don't know about.

Currently, I can only assume that this is intentional because it provides meta-programming functionality using template parameters, which is simply unnecessary in my current situation. So why can't nonliteral types be returned in constexpr in the first place? I know there are many questions in this thread, but perhaps a single answer will suffice for all of them.

For the sake of clarity, run the following:

```
class CustomType
{
public:
    inline CustomType(const int& val)
        : _value(val) {}

    inline constexpr auto Value() const { return _value; }

private:
    int _value;
};

template<int N>
class A
{
public:
    inline constexpr A(const CustomType& Val)
        : _value(Val) {}
    inline ~A() {}

    inline constexpr A(const A& rhs)
        : _value(rhs._value) {}
    inline constexpr const A& operator=(const A& rhs) const { return rhs; }

    inline constexpr auto Value() const { return _value; }
private:
    const CustomType _value;
};
```

If you remove `template<int N>` the code will no longer compile.

Comment: Are you instantiating `A` when adding templates?

Comment: can you please show real code? My compiler does not understand `// ... some templates` and btw me neither

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: A similar case [Why do templates allow constexpr function members with non-constexpr constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568820/why-do-templates-allow-constexpr-function-members-with-non-constexpr-constructor?rq=1)

Comment: Bo Persson, thanks for the comment, but it doesn't seem to explain this situation, because no specialization would satisfy the constexpr requirement since it is always `CustomType`.

Comment: @BoPersson to my mind it perfectly explains the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the most recent standards draft, [[dcl.constexpr]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6) (my emphasis):

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor, that specialization is still a constexpr function or constexpr constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression. **If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.**

---

Your function plainly fails to satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function, since its return type is not a literal type. This, combined with the clauses quoted above, would lead you to believe that your code is in fact ill-formed, *no diagnostic required* (which is pretty much what happens). I would expect any constexpr use of the member function to result in a diagnostic, though.

See also [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598013/147845) to the question *[Why do templates allow constexpr function members with non-constexpr constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26568820/147845)* which deals with exactly the same case, except the function happens to be a free function as opposed to a member function.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means that the member function is ill-formed, but that doesn't prevent the compiler from guessing what I want.  In this case the compiler probably just omits constexpr in the generic version.

Comment: @AOK: Not really. It means that it is ill-formed, only that deciding that it is in fact ill-formed in general requires enumerating all possible template parameters (which is impossible), and the compiler therefore doesn't have to issue a diagnostic. The compiler hardly guesses what you want; rather, it simply allows you to use the (still formally constexpr) function in non-constexpr contexts like any other constexpr function. It doesn't "omit constexpr".

Comment: Thanks, this finally explains why the code both compiles and runs without producing unexpected results.

Comment: @aok As an editorial, basically solving this in the general case is *hard*.  So the standard doesn't require compilers to detect this.  But it permits compilers to detect it.  However, how it permits ill formed without requiring detection here is amazingly liberal.  No decent compiler will exploit this to say format your HDD or email your most viewed files to your grandparent, right?  But that would be standard compliant.

Answer (score 0):

The method in your template class isn't really instantiated until you actually use it. Maybe the compiler checks its syntax sanity but never the semantics.

Comment: Adding this to main: `A<1> test(CustomType{ 1 });` compiles.

Comment: Hmm yes I guess I am wrong on that.

Comment: @AOK you need to also call `Value()` otherwise the method will not be instantiated. The compiler does not do more than it needs to when instantiating the template

Comment: @tobi303 yes but the problem persist even after you explicitly instantiate the method i.e. call it. It must be something else.

Comment: Indeed. Add `std::cout << test.Value().Value();` and it compiles and outputs results as you would expect.

Comment: But the `test.Value()` in this context is **not** constexpr call. Try to use it constexpr-tly you'll get the same error...